# Save a variable in an ec2's bash and append it to caddy file using terraform

Tags: linux, bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a user-data set on an ec2 resource deployment which has the following

```
user_data = <<-EOF
    sudo su
    cd ~
    sleep 20
    sudo public_ip=$(curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com)
    sudo touch /var/log/caddy/caddy_access.log
    echo -en $public_ip.nip.io '{ \nlog { \noutput file /var/log/caddy/caddy_access.log \n} \nreverse_proxy / localhost:3000 localhost:3001 { \nlb_policy round_robin \n}\n}' > Caddyfile
    sudo caddy start
    EOF
```

More bash scripts above handle the installation, etc, which are successful. Only the Public_Ip isn't storing that variable / or isn't fetching anything. This is the Caddyfile that gets created

```
.nip.io { 
     log { 
         output file /var/log/caddy/caddy_access.log 
     } 
     reverse_proxy / localhost:3000 localhost:3001 { 
         lb_policy round_robin 
     }
}
```

This does work when I either ssh or connect to the instance and run the commands myself. So, I don't know if elastic IP assignment takes place after the instance deployment and sleep has no effect on it whatsoever or if terraform interpolates the `$` sign as something else and what would be the right way to do this assignment.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried maybe `public_ip="${self.public_ip}"`?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, I tried it in the instance and got the following `bash: ${self.public_ip}: bad substitution`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Caddyfile syntax. Can you help by showing the output you expect? Also, are you using any Terraform to interpolate the `user_data` and insert Terraform variables? How is the `user_data` getting onto the ec2 instance? And when you say "this does work," do you mean that the Caddyfile is being generatead differently in that case? Or that the one you've shown is behaving as expected once Caddy is run somewhere?